# Calculating pairwise rolling correlations

Tags: vba, excel

Please find the workbook [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iyc9bvh7c1mqlms/Calculating%20Rolling%20Correlations.xlsx)

The first row contains the names of the banks and all other entries are the daily returns of each bank. What I want to do is find the rolling correlation (from the past 1 year of returns) of pairwise banks beginning from 1/1/2008, I'll provide an example of what I want to do:

Starting with ERSTE GROUP BANK, on the date JAN 1st 2008, I want to find the correlation between ERSTE GROUP BANK and RAIFFEISEN BANK INTL based on the past 1 year worth of returns, so the formula would be =CORREL(B2:B263,C2:C263), similarly on JAN 2nd 2008 the formula would be =CORREL(B3:B264,C3:C264) and so on until Feb 28th 2013.

Then I want to do the same thing but now on the date JAN 1st 2008, I find the pairwise correlation between ERSTE GROUP BANK and DEXIA, hence the formula on JAN 1st 2008 would be =CORREL(B2:B263,D2:D263) and so on until Feb 28th 2013.

So essentially I want to find the pairwise correlations between ERSTE GROUP BANK and every other bank like this, from 1/1/2008-28/2/2013.

Then I want to repeat this with ALL the other banks, eg, now take RAIFFEISEN BANK INTL as the 'primary' bank and from 1/1/2008-28/2/2013, I want to find the pairwise correlation between RAIFFEISEN BANK INTL and ERSTE GROUP BANK, then RAIFFEISEN BANK INTL and DEXIA etc.

Does anyone have an idea on how to write a macro for this? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: This is the code I have currently, which works, but only for one bank, I would like to have the code automatically do it for all other banks too.

```
Sub correlations()
'
' 
'

'
    Range("C1:Z1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=5
    Range("AC1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 21
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 22
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 15
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 20
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 24
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 27
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 33
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 36
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 40
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 42
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 47
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 49
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 51
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 53
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 56
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 58
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 60
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 65
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 67
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 69
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 74
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 76
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 78
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 80
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 87
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 89
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 94
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 96
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 98
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 103
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 112
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 116
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 118
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 120
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 123
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 127
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 129
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 134
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 141
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 145
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 147
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 152
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 154
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 156
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 159
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 161
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 163
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 165
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 170
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 176
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 179
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 188
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 192
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 199
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 205
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 208
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 212
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 217
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 223
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 226
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 230
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 232
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 237
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 239
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 241
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 243
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 246
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 248
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 252
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 257
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 259
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 261
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 266
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 270
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 275
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 277
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 279
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 284
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 286
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 288
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 293
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 295
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 299
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 304
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 306
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 311
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 313
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 317
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 319
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 324
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 326
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 328
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 335
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 337
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 340
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 344
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 349
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 351
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 353
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 355
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 357
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 360
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 362
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 364
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 366
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 371
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 373
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 378
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 380
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 384
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 387
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 389
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 391
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 393
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 400
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 402
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 407
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 409
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 411
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 416
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 418
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 420
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 422
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 425
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 427
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 429
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 425
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 416
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 413
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 409
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 402
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 393
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 384
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 380
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 375
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 369
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 364
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 362
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 355
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 353
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 351
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 349
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 346
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 344
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 342
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 340
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 337
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 335
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 333
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 328
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 326
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 324
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 322
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 317
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 315
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 311
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 308
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 306
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 304
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 302
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 299
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 297
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 295
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 293
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 290
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 288
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 286
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 284
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 281
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 277
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 275
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 273
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 270
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 268
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 266
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 264
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 261
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 259
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 257
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 255
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 252
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 250
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 246
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 239
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 237
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 232
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 230
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 228
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 226
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 223
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 221
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 217
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 214
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 210
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 208
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 210
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 214
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 223
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 230
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 235
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 241
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 243
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 248
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 250
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 252
    Range("AC263").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CORREL(R[-261]C2:RC2,R[-261]C[-26]:RC[-26])"
    Range("AC264").Select
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 19
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 20
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 21
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 22
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 23
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 24
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 25
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 26
    Range("AC263").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AC263:AZ263"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("AC263:AZ263").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AC263:AZ1610"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("AC263:AZ1610").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot come here without having tried anything, with your input data and the functionality you want. The point of this site is helping you with specific problems, not doing the work which you should be doing. Do some research and some test, try to create a loop performing the actions you want; if you get stuck, come back here, post the code you tried and tell the specific problem you have.

Comment: @varocarbas Oh actually I've tried a lot, I will edit my post with my attempted codes.

Comment: Yes, please. Just post a code showing that you have tried something, that you put some effort on this and have a minimal understanding. Also it would be useful to understand the kind of help you need.

Comment: To save you some computation time FYI, CORREL is linear correlation. If you have done ERSTE with DEXIA then there is no need to do DEXIA with ERSTE.